# Windows 10 Resolution stuck by 800 x 600

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have Windows 10, lately I can't update any resolution. It stucks.

I've tried update my device driver and windows update already

[image: k at]

[image]

All of a sudden this happen for 1 week now.

Please help !

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I don’t know what else to tell. I’m on windows 10. PC Desktop on a windows that I build. The graphic card is nvedia

Comment: Your screenshot is cropped in such a way vital information is missing.  You have not indicated what Nvidia card you have.

Comment: Can you please share information that you find by looking at your graphics card in Device Manager? Depending on your exact card, the fix may differ.

Comment: Updated with that now

Comment: Try a quick repair. Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth .  Follow with SFC /SCANNOW . When complete, restart and test

Comment: Looks like the GTX970 is deactivated. I'd check your PCIe 6+2 pin supply connectors on the card. Maybe one is loose?

Comment: Please double click on your GTX 970 and post us the error codes you are getting. Also, download the driver directly from Geforce: https://us.download.nvidia.com/Windows/441.87/441.87-desktop-win10-64bit-international-dch-whql.exe

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show us the error message, so this might not be a solution, but learning from experience this kind of driver problem is mostly because you've picked the wrong driver.

To see which driver you need to install, you need to check the it's driver HWID, and look it up on Google for the right driver.

[image]

If this doesn't work, you might want to let Windows Update to install the correct driver automatically. Windows does a good job for that.

Comment: They did say they've updated the device drivers automatically. This uses the windows update repertoire iirc. And they said they tried windows update...so drivers should be the correct one.

Comment: I think you should at least try to install the correct Nvidia [driver](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/156281/en-us) and see if this solves the issue

Comment: @NatsuKage - The author might have said they updated the driver but the Device Manager says an entirely different story.  The GPU has been identified by Windows, which means it at least has power, difficult to determine the reason Windows thinks there is a problem though.

Comment: @Ramhound I've seen this usually for bad drivers indeed. But it may be a hardware fault. Need more input to be sure...